# Display Edit Button Upon Checked Checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox, dynamic

I have an HTML `Table` with the last column being a column with `checkboxes`.
I want it be so that whenever I check the `checkbox`, an edit button pops up right next to the table and allows me to edit that row.

Right now, on load, the edit button is already there and when a checkbox is checked, it does nothing.

How can I fix this?

HTML/PHP code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stage Rebate Master HTML Table</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="html_master.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src=jquery-1.8.3.js></script>
        <script src="html_master.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<table id="html_master">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <td>MR_ID</td>
    <td>MR_Name</td>
    <td>Buyer_ID</td>
    <td>MR_POC_N</td>
    <td>MR_POC_E</td>
    <td>MR_POC_P</td>
    <td>Select</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td id="mr_id"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td id="mr_name"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td id="buyer_id"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td id="poc_n"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td id="poc_e"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td id="poc_p"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="checked"></td>
        </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</tbody>
        <input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('html_master')">  
        <input type="button" id="edit" value="Edit" name="edit">
        <input type="button" id="delRow" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow('html_master')">
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Relative Javascript:

```
     // ----- Delete Row -----

function deleteRow(html_master){
    var tbl=document.getElementById(html_master);
    var col=tbl.querySelectorAll('input[type=\"checkbox\"]:checked');
    if( col ){
        for( var n in col )if( col[ n ].nodeType==1 ){
            try {
                var tr=col[ n ].parentNode.parentNode;
                var tbody=tr.parentNode;
                tbody.removeChild( tr );
            }catch( err ){
                console.warn(err);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

// ----- Add Row -----

function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = rowCount;

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell2.appendChild(element2);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type = "text";
    element3.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell3.appendChild(element3);

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var element4 = document.createElement("input");
    element4.type = "text";
    element4.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell4.appendChild(element4);

    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var element5 = document.createElement("input");
    element5.type = "text";
    element5.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell5.appendChild(element5);

    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    var element6 = document.createElement("input");
    element6.type = "text";
    element6.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell6.appendChild(element6);

    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
    var element7 = document.createElement("input");
    element7.type = "checkbox";
    element7.name="chkbox[]";
    cell7.appendChild(element7);

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $submit = $("#edit").hide(),
    $cbs = $('input[name="check"]').click(function() {
      $submit.toggle($cbs.is(":checked"));
    });
});
```

DB Code:

```
<?php
$host="xxxxxx"; 
$dbName="xxxxxxx"; 
$dbUser="xxxxx"; 
$dbPass="xxxxxxxxxxxx";

$dbh = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=".$host."; Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass); 
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Stage_Rebate_Master ORDER BY MR_ID ASC"; 
?>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
    background-image: url("background.png");
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: 1.5px solid black;
    padding: 3px;
}

thead {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: what does your console read? Plus, this seems db-related; you sure that that isn't part of the problem?

Comment: It is db-related but neither the checkbox nor the edit button have anything to do with the database so I wouldn't think that would be a problem.

Comment: ok, well you've an answer below.

Comment: Works as supplied: [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r6v7esdz/), unless you have some odd css styles

Comment: Well thats odd...it doesn't work for me whenever I run it on my server...is there a reason it works in one place and not the other?

Comment: well, if that fiddle and answer say your code works, then it's something else. You say it isn't db-related so you'll need to take it up with the answer given below or post your PHP and db code. There isn't anything I can add to this. All I can say is check your console (again) and errors via PHP and your db.

Comment: Do you have a live example that can be looked at? More than likely you aren't supplying some code that is actually causing the issue

Comment: I noticed the edit with the PDO/SELECT. However your code suggest an edit being UPDATE and we don't know if that's what the ultimate goal is and if that is failing or not.

Comment: I updated the code to include my DB connection and the entire javascript code...the end goal is after editing, it saves that information to the DB

Comment: also added my CSS code...

Comment: *"it saves that information to the DB"* - That is either an INSERT or UPDATE; I don't see that in your newly edited post. Sorry, but commenting like this back and forth isn't helping here. I'll have to poass on this, sorry. I sincerely wish you well on this.

Comment: There is no insert or update yet because I haven't gotten to that yet...i want to figure out this first problem first before i move on to writing that query

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work, but this is likely easier to understand

```
$(function() {
   var $edit = $("#edit"); 
   $edit.hide() // or use CSS
   $('input[name="check"]').click(function() {
    $edit.toggle($this).is(":checked") );
   });
 });
```

However it will hide the button again if one of the checkboxes are unchecked regardless of other checkboxes

Perhaps you mean

```
$('input[name="check"]').click(function() {
  $edit.toggle($('input[name="check"]:checked').length>0);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This also helped!

Answer (score -1):

Figured out my problem...i simply didn't have my jquery source correct...I changed it to...

```
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"
```

Now it works just fine!

Comment: Down vote for sharing the correct answer to my problem? Interesting.